# Function call on specific directive instance on keyboard press

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was wondering if it is possible to call a the function on a specific directive instance **when a global keyboard shortcut is pressed if it has the class focused based on ng-class**.

Here is some template code:

**home.html**

```
<body ng-controller="SampleController">
   <test-question
      ng-repeat="n in [1,2,3]"
      ng-class="{'focused': tracer.focus == n}"
      focusnum = "{{n}}"
      ng-click="tracer.focus = n"
      >
      Test Question {{n}}
    </test-question>
</body>
```

**home.js**

```
angular.module('sampleApp', [])
  .controller("SampleController", function($scope) {
    $scope.tracer = {
        focus: 1
    }
    // on keyboard shortcut call some function on a specific directive with class focused
  })
  .directive('testQuestion', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
          scope.someFunction = function() {};
        }
    }
  });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/P7rM3o4TADSf6rxTIRsZ?p=info

Answer (score 0):

Try coming at it from another angle. Make a directive that binds to a value in your main controller. WIthin that directive watch that value and when it gets set to true, for example, call the method within the directive.

In your main controller you can make the keypress shortcut set the necessary value to true based on focus that is also maintained in your main controller. Something like this

```
     angular.module('sampleApp', []).controller("SampleController", function($scope) {

        $scope.childDirectiveFlags = {dir1:false,dir2:false,dir3:false};
        $scope.currentFocus = 'dir1';

         // on keypress event set the flag to true in the directive you want action to
         // happen on

         $scope.childDirectiveFlags[$scope.currentFocus] = true; // Will trigger watch
     };

     sampleApp.directive = directive('testQuestion', function() {
       return {
         restrict: 'E',
         scope : {
            watchValue: '@'
         },
         link: function(scope, el, attrs) {

           scope.$watch('watchValue',function() {
               if(scope.watchValue) {
                    scope.someFunction();
                    scope.watchValue = false;
               }
           });
           scope.someFunction = function() {};
           }
         }
     });
```

Comment: Thanks Scott! Is there a way to do this without storing `$scope.childDirectiveFlags = {dir1:false,dir2:false,dir3:false};` in the model? Because we already have directives right so I'm thinking there might be some way to use their attributes instead to target a specific directive

Comment: Of course there is the $rootscope.broadcast feature. But this will still call all directives which doesn't seem the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: Sure, you can use any value as long as you bind to it.That was just an example.